# How to get live app usage stats in android

Tags: java, android, usage-statistics, usagestatsmanager

The below code tracks todays usage of an app every second to get accurate usage time. The issue is it logs the same usage time every second, which is the usage time when the app was opened. The usage time does not change until the user reopens the app. The usage time should increase while I am using the app but it does not, how I can get live usage time of that app.

```
        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                long startMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                List<UsageStats> usageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,startMillis, currentTime);
                for(UsageStats stat : usageStats){
                    if(stat.getPackageName().equals(getPackageName())){
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "Usage time: " + stat.getTotalTimeVisible());
                        }
                    }
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
```

Heres the log while using the app(does not change if the app is running in foreground):

```
2024-02-25 17:30:22.840 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
2024-02-25 17:30:23.851 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
2024-02-25 17:30:24.864 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
2024-02-25 17:30:25.874 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
2024-02-25 17:30:26.885 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
2024-02-25 17:30:27.894 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
2024-02-25 17:30:28.906 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
2024-02-25 17:30:29.916 13942-13942 MainActivity            com.prototype1                       D  Usage time: 1435719
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're polling `getTotalTimeVisible` every second, the time interval that you provide to `queryUsageStats` method through `beginTime` and `endTime` parameters is always the same (and refers to the past).

Because of that, the `getTotalTimeVisible` method call will always give you back the same value.

Comment: I tried using different `beginTime`  like `List<UsageStats> usageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,currentTime - 10000, currentTime);` but its still the same issue.

Comment: you should invoke `queryUsageStats` method every second with the proper parameters

Comment: Moved the `usageStats` initialization into the run method as in the edited question, but the behavior of the output still does not changed